# How to leave data online and then retrieve it into Android App

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating a language app in which there will be lectures in video forms.
So, the problem that I am having is that if I store all the videos in the package, then it will get bulky, which will not be suitable for a nice user experience. So I want to know if I can leave those videos somewhere online and then retrieve it into the app to play, it as this thing will not take space on user's device.

Please tell me if anyone has any solution regarding it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Youtube links, than you can create a database and store those links in the database and then you can play those youtube videos in your app.

Comment: I was using it but since it is a third party api, so its against google play policies